# Runtime synchronization failed in MobileFirst 7.0 Server

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

[image]

Found this error while deploying adapters to worklight console. And we had a workaround by restarting the application server (apache tomcat).

Logs related to this :

log file : `catalina.2015-07-16.log`

```
SEVERE: Operation to deploy adapter 'LoginHTTPAdapter' failed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1348)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.removeAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:171)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.destroy(AuthenticationContext.java:332)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.AdapterSessionContainer.destroyAdapterSessions(AdapterSessionContainer.java:71)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.closeAdapterResources(AdapterManagerImpl.java:144)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.deployAdapter(AdapterManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.AdapterDeployAction.commit(AdapterDeployAction.java:50)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:203)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***

Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter setSyncRequired
INFO: FWLSE0273I: Set sync required to 'true' [project worklight]
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean sync
SEVERE: FWLSE0081E: Failed synchronizing application from the administration service. This prevents the application from running. The reason is There was an error during the rollback, the runtime is not in sync with the other nodes. Status CombineStatusMessage [children=[StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='removeAttribute: Session already invalidated', timestamp=1437028119197, detailedMessage=java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1348)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.removeAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:171)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.destroy(AuthenticationContext.java:332)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.AdapterSessionContainer.destroyAdapterSessions(AdapterSessionContainer.java:71)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.closeAdapterResources(AdapterManagerImpl.java:144)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.deployAdapter(AdapterManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.AdapterDeployAction.commit(AdapterDeployAction.java:50)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:203)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***

]], super=StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='Commit', timestamp=1437028119197, detailedMessage=null]]. Please restart the application server after taking the proper corrective actions. [project worklight]
OutOfSyncException [receivedTransactionDetails=com.worklight.common.type.TransactionDetails{currentTransactionId=1437028119196, previousTransactionId=1437028118819 is dbMaster=false, lastTransactionID=1437028118819]
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:213)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***

Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM StatusMessage createStatusMessage
SEVERE: Synchronize operation failed.
OutOfSyncException [receivedTransactionDetails=com.worklight.common.type.TransactionDetails{currentTransactionId=1437028119196, previousTransactionId=1437028118819 is dbMaster=false, lastTransactionID=1437028118819]
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:213)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***

Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.JMXCommunicationUtil logOperationResult
SEVERE: Result: worklight: null///192.168.135.4: Runtime synchronization failed
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.JMXCommunicationUtil logOperationResult
INFO: worklight: null///192.168.135.4: 2015-07-16T06:28:38.819Z: Preparation to deploy 'DuDuHuanBao' finished
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.JMXCommunicationUtil logOperationResult
INFO: worklight: null///192.168.135.4: 2015-07-16T06:28:39.196Z: Preparation to deploy adapter 'LoginHTTPAdapter' finished successfully, FWLSE0103W: Procedure 'onLogout' will always require authentication when connectAs='endUser'. [project worklight]
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.JMXCommunicationUtil logOperationResult
SEVERE: worklight: null///192.168.135.4: 2015-07-16T06:28:39.198Z: There was an error during the rollback, the runtime is not in sync with the other nodes. Status CombineStatusMessage [children=[StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='removeAttribute: Session already invalidated', timestamp=1437028119197, detailedMessage=java.lang.IllegalStateException: removeAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttribute(StandardSession.java:1348)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.removeAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:171)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.destroy(AuthenticationContext.java:332)
    at com.worklight.integration.model.AdapterSessionContainer.destroyAdapterSessions(AdapterSessionContainer.java:71)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.closeAdapterResources(AdapterManagerImpl.java:144)
    at com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.deployAdapter(AdapterManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.AdapterDeployAction.commit(AdapterDeployAction.java:50)
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:203)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***

]], super=StatusMessage [severity=ERROR, message='Commit', timestamp=1437028119197, detailedMessage=null]]
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM StatusMessage createStatusMessage
SEVERE: Cannot synchronized
com.worklight.core.exceptions.ProjectSynchronizationException: Runtime synchronization failed
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:342)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    *** ***

Caused by: OutOfSyncException [receivedTransactionDetails=com.worklight.common.type.TransactionDetails{currentTransactionId=1437028119196, previousTransactionId=1437028118819 is dbMaster=false, lastTransactionID=1437028118819]
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:213)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    ... 42 more

Jul 16, 2015 2:28:39 PM com.ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.JMXCommunicationUtil logOperationResult
SEVERE: Result: worklight: null///192.168.135.4: Runtime synchronization failed
Jul 16, 2015 2:28:49 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.RuntimeMBeanHandler getRMIConnection
INFO: Establishing RMI connection on localhost with port number 8686
```

log file : `localhost.2015-07-16.log`

```
Jul 16, 2015 10:02:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ManagementServlet] in context with path [/wladmin] threw exception
<openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:523)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:719)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:684)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:661)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementService.loginAudit(ManagementService.java:132)

    *** ***

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4246)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4211)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:934)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.retainConnection(JDBCStoreManager.java:216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.retainConnection(DelegatingStoreManager.java:163)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.retainConnection(BrokerImpl.java:3734)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beginStoreManagerTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:1302)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1987)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1927)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1845)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1369)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:877)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:512)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 85,896,513 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3317)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2690)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5093)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:198)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:198)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.setAutoCommit(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:117)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.<init>(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:111)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.decorate(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:93)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.decorate(DecoratingDataSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connectInternal(JDBCStoreManager.java:945)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:930)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3298)
    ... 105 more

Jul 16, 2015 2:28:47 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn expire
WARNING: SSO unable to expire session [Host: [localhost], Context: [/worklightconsole], SessionID: [1690FBC4A81ABB560ECC9203CC2CC8D2]] because the Session could not be found
Jul 16, 2015 2:31:35 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn expire
WARNING: SSO unable to expire session [Host: [localhost], Context: [/worklightconsole], SessionID: [185C6AA9E08F71E4A4F16E689D0FD426]] because the Session could not be found
Jul 16, 2015 2:32:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GadgetAPIServlet] in context with path [/worklight] threw exception [OutOfSyncException [receivedTransactionDetails=com.worklight.common.type.TransactionDetails{currentTransactionId=1437028119196, previousTransactionId=1437028118819 is dbMaster=false, lastTransactionID=1437028118819]] with root cause
OutOfSyncException [receivedTransactionDetails=com.worklight.common.type.TransactionDetails{currentTransactionId=1437028119196, previousTransactionId=1437028118819 is dbMaster=false, lastTransactionID=1437028118819]
    at com.worklight.twopc.runtime.RuntimeTransactionHandler.commit(RuntimeTransactionHandler.java:213)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectSynchronizationBean.sync(ProjectSynchronizationBean.java:265)
    at com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.sync(ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl.java:1045)

    *** ***
```

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the handling of MySQL stale connections. The MySQL database closes its connections after a period of non-activity on a connection. This timeout is defined by the system variable called wait_timeout. The default is 28000 seconds (8 hours).

To avoid this behavior look at : 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_handling_stale_mysql_connections.html?lang=en

Comment: HI Bruno, I am getting the same error in WAS ND 8.5.5.6 full profile. Please let me know any fix or settings required.

Comment: The link above describes also the procedure for WAS

Comment: Thank Bruno. I got this error due to Java Heap Size. One of the Android WLAPP file deployed in the console is huge and the restart after minimal-update is not able to load that file, this gives the error "Runtime Synchronization failed". Once increase the Java heap size and restart server its working fine. Thanks again.